# Changing grub2 background

Tags: fedora, grub2, boot-loader

so I've been trying to change my grub background for a while and nothing I have tried has worked.

Current info:

Fedora 26

grub2.x86_64

Resolution: 1920x1080

All images used were rgb non-indexed, matched to grub2 resolution at (1920x1080) (1080x720) (650x1080) and (saved)

I have tried setting it with grub customizer. And running

`sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`

This changes text and highlight colors but has no effect on the background.

Tried vbeinfo to edit GFXMode and GFXPayload during boot but command was not found. Most of the guides I find are for an older version of Fedora, Debian, or older grub.

Update:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT="-1"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="$(sed 's, release .*$,,g' /etc/system-release)"
GRUB_DEFAULT="saved"
GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU="true"
GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="console"<-- Deleted this line
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="rhgb quiet"
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

export GRUB_COLOR_NORMAL="white/dark-gray"
export GRUB_COLOR_HIGHLIGHT="magenta/light-gray"
GRUB_BACKGROUND="/boot/grub2/background.tga"
GRUB_GFXMODE="1920x1080,1440x900,1024x768,auto"
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX="keep"
GRUB_FONT="/boot/efi/EFI/fedora/unicode.pf2"
```

After removing `GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT` this line was added when I ran `grub2-mkconfig`:

```
Found background: /boot/grub2/background.tga
```

Actual background does not show but the color has changed to grey from black

Answer (score 1):

you need to edit your `/etc/default/grub` file, you need to search for a

`GRUB_BACKGROUND="/path/to/myimage"`

After enabling it you need to save your config.

Here is a very useful [guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB/Tips_and_tricks) to edit all related to your grub config

Comment: Thanks for the guide. I already had GRUB_BACKGROUND set correctly, but just realized I am in console mode. Fixed that and got a solid grey instead of black

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you already have done some research. I can't find anything about filesize limitations. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Displays recommends making modifications in GRUB for interactive editing and troubleshooting. You could also start with an existing theme that uses a full background image, I modified one to get a very simple theme to increase my bootime (gfxmode for some reason saves 100ms). http://wiki.rosalab.ru/en/index.php/Grub2_theme_/_reference may be useful. It's unlikely but there may be an issue with the GRUB package itself, I compared the Fedora and Ubuntu packages in the past, they have a lot of patches applied to mainline GRUB, so trying a different distro may be a good way to check for that. Sorry this should rather have been a comment but was to long and I don't have much time at the moment to investigate further.